# Connecting from a local web application to Google's apprtc.appspot.com. Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I've tried to connect to apprtc.appspot.com from my web application which was on localhost and couldn't because apprtc.appspot.com prohibited making ajax calls because of same origin policy. However, maybe it was me who did something wrong.

The question is: is there any way to connect from a web application running locally to apprtc.appspot.com?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not:

- It seems like apprtc.appspot.com does not support [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), so there should be no way that you can make ajax calls from your web front end to apprtc's back end.
- There are WebRTC frameworks that are completely web socket-based and allow connecting to their back end from front ends hosted by other servers, e.g. [easyrtc](http://easyrtc.com/docs/guides/easyrtc_with_other_servers.php). However, apprtc.appspot.com is not purely web socket-based, but seems to do part of the signalling via http.
- There are providers of WebRTC infrastructure-as-a-Service, you can use for your purpose, e.g. Telefonixa's [tokbox](https://tokbox.com/opentok/quick-start/)